# Print values in list 2 through arraylist

Tags: java, sql

i have 2 lists list 1 and list2 now i need to do a search in list 2 compared to list 1 if that element exisists 
i have written down the code but it is not printing?

```
Iterator<String> it=list1.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext())
      {
          if(list2.contains(it.next()))
          {
            System.out.println(list2);

          }


      }
```

Comment: For all we know, your lists are empty.

Comment: I'm confused as to exactly what the question is.  Is the question that if the item from list1 is found in list2 you want to print that individual item?  your code is essentially calling .toString on the list object and your question isn't quite clear.

Comment: please post you code where you insert data into lists, and iterator implementation

Comment: You're printing out `list2`, not the value that you just found in `list2`.

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- At least one of your lists is empty.
- They have no objects in common.
- The class which you use does not implement `equals` correctly.

Comment: I have printed 2 lists and they have elemts in common

Answer (score 3):

try

```
for(String s : list1){
   if(list2.contains(s)){
          System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

based on that both lists contain String objects

Comment: Who said he uses Strings? And this isn't even correct Java syntax. The `in` keyword doesn't exist. You should use a colon. (`:`). Plus, this won't make any difference (except the compilation errors). His problem is that it is printing nothing. Printing something else will still result in nothing printed.

Comment: thanks, brain in javascript :) , he uses Iterator<String> , +1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure neither list is empty and the definitely have something in common, then try:

```
for(String str in list1)
    if(list2.contains(str))
        System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: nop dude i am sure that list has elements  but it not printing
when i print   SOP(list1) and SOP(lsit2) it is printing. But i want a list that is records that are common in both